# How can I use grep to find a word inside a folder?

Tags: string, command-line, grep, keyword-search, file-search

In Windows, I would have done a search for finding a word inside a folder. Similarly, I want to know if a specific word occurs inside a directory containing many sub-directories and files. My searches for grep syntax shows I must specify the filename, i.e. `grep string filename`.

Now, I do not know the filename, so what do I do?
A friend suggested to do `grep -nr string`, but I don't know what this means and I got no results with it (there is no response until I issue a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>).

Answer (score 1113, accepted):

```
grep -nr 'yourString*' .
```

The dot at the end searches the current directory. Meaning for each parameter:

```
-n            Show relative line number in the file
'yourString*' String for search, followed by a wildcard character
-r            Recursively search subdirectories listed
.             Directory for search (current directory)
```

`grep -nr 'MobileAppSer*' .`  (Would find `MobileAppServlet.java` or `MobileAppServlet.class` or `MobileAppServlet.txt`; `'MobileAppASer*.*'` is another way to do the same thing.)

To check more parameters use **man grep** command.

Comment: What's the business with `*`? It will either result in shell wildcard expansion (if there are filenames matching the wildcard pattern), or grep will take it as 0-or-more repetition operator for the character preceding `*`.

Comment: Now let's consider both possibilities for `grep -nr MobileAppSer* .` 1. Assume we have 3 files in the current directory matching `MobileAppSer*` wildcard pattern: named `MobileAppServlet.java`, `MobileAppServlet.class`, `MobileAppServlet.txt`. Then `grep` will be invoked like this: `grep -nr MobileAppServlet.class MobileAppServlet.java MobileAppServlet.txt .`. It means search for text "MobileAppServlet.class" in files MobileAppServlet.java, MobileAppServlet.txt, and elsewhere in the current directory - which surely isn't what the user wants here.

Comment: 2. In case there are no files in the current directory matching the `MobileAppSer*` wildcard pattern, `grep` will receive the argument `MobileAppSer*` as-is and thus will take it as search for text "MobileAppSe" followed by 0 or more occurrences of "r", so it will attempt to find texts "MobileAppSe", "MobileAppSer", "MobileAppSerr", "MobileAppSerrr", etc. in current directory's files contents - not what the user wants either.

Comment: This is a dubious choice of regex. Usta has pointed this out.

Comment: I ran `grep -nr 'yourString*' .` and got some files with "binary file matches". You can add `--text` or `-a` to prevent this: `grep -anr 'yourString*' .`

Comment: I think you want to remove the asterisk: `grep -anr 'yourString' .`

Answer (score 159):

```
grep -nr string my_directory
```

Additional notes: this satisfies the syntax `grep [options] string filename` because in Unix-like systems, a directory is a kind of file (there is a term "regular file" to specifically refer to entities that are called just "files" in Windows).

`grep -nr string` reads the content to search from the standard input, that is why it just waits there for input from you, and stops doing so when you press ^C (it would stop on ^D as well, which is the key combination for end-of-file).

Comment: Hey, so if i want to search for a string irrespective of the case, must I do this: grep -i -nr "my word" .

Comment: @kiki: Yes, which is equivalent to `grep -inr "my word" .`

Comment: @kiki: `-r` for grep means search in subdirectories recursively and `-n` means prefix each line of output with the corresponding line number of the file which contains that line. `man grep` describes all of this, and much more.

Answer (score 74):

**GREP**: Global Regular Expression Print/Parser/Processor/Program.
You can use this to search the current directory. 
You can specify -R for "recursive", which means the program searches in all subfolders, and their subfolders, and their subfolder's subfolders, etc.

```
grep -R "your word" .
```

`-n` will print the line number, where it matched in the file.
`-i` will search case-insensitive (capital/non-capital letters).

```
grep -inR "your regex pattern" .
```

Comment: ./* means all files in the current directory, -R means recursive (searching subdirectories etc.)

Comment: Thanks. And `grep -inR "[0-9a-fA-F]{32}" .` helps find hashes (which are hex strings) in the files within the current directory. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724915/470749

Answer (score 40):

There's also:

```
find directory_name -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -li word
```

but that might be a bit much for a beginner.

`find` is a general purpose directory walker/lister, `-type f` means "look for plain files rather than directories and named pipes and what have you", `-print0` means "print them on the standard output using null characters as delimiters". The output from `find` is sent to `xargs -0` and that grabs its standard input in chunks (to avoid command line length limitations) using null characters as a record separator (rather than the standard newline) and then applies `grep -li word` to each set of files. On the `grep`, `-l` means "list the files that match" and `-i` means "case insensitive"; you can usually combine single character options so you'll see `-li` more often than `-l -i`.

If you don't use `-print0` and `-0` then you'll run into problems with file names that contain spaces so using them is a good habit.

Comment: can I exclude certain directories? @muistooshort

Comment: @Ferologics There should be, check `man find` from the command line to see what options your `find` supports.

Comment: "but that might be a bit much for a beginner" -- the length doesn't change depending on your personal experience!

Answer (score 29):

```
grep -nr search_string search_dir
```

will do a RECURSIVE (meaning the directory and all it's sub-directories) search for the search_string. (as correctly answered by usta).

The reason you were not getting any anwers with your friend's suggestion of:

```
grep -nr string
```

is because no directory was specified. If you are in the directory that you want to do the search in, you have to do the following:

```
grep -nr string .
```

It is important to include the '.' character, as this tells grep to search THIS directory.

Comment: Hi, what do i do, if i have to search 2 words with a space in between? Should the words be specified within quotes? i.e        grep -nr "my word" .

Answer (score 13):

Why not do a recursive search to find all instances in sub directories:

```
grep -r 'text' *
```

This works like a charm.

Comment: No need to quote search string with no special chars like spaces

Answer (score 10):

Similar to the answer posted by @eLRuLL, an easier way to specify a search that respects word boundaries is to use the `-w` option:

```
grep -wnr "yourString" .
```

Comment: In the cmd prompt or windows terminal the term grep is not recognized

Comment: @kouty grep is a Unix command. https://www.itechtics.com/using-findstr-windows/

Answer (score 5):

Another option that I like to use:

```
find folder_name -type f -exec grep your_text  {} \;
```

-type f returns you only files and not folders

-exec and {} runs the grep on the files that were found in the search (the exact syntax is "-exec command {}").

Answer (score 5):

1. `grep -r "yourstring" *`
   Will find "yourstring" in any files and folders

Now if you want to look for two different strings at the same time you can always use option E and add words for the search. example after the break

2. `grep -rE "yourstring|yourotherstring|$" *` will search for list locations where `yourstring` or `yourotherstring` matches

Answer (score 5):

```
grep -R "string" /directory/
```

-R follows also symlinks when -r does not.

Answer (score 4):

The answer you selected is fine, and it works, but it isn't the correct way to do it, because:

```
grep -nr yourString* .
```

This actually searches the  string `"yourStrin"` and `"g"` 0 or many times.

So the proper way to do it is:

```
grep -nr \w*yourString\w* .
```

This command searches the string with any character before and after on the current folder.

Comment: however `grep -nr yourString` works too, as it looks for the bare `yourString` anywhere in the line (or at least it does on my system, OSX Lion)

Answer (score 2):

The following sample looks recursively for `your search string` in the `*.xml` and `*.js` files located somewhere inside the folders `path1`, `path2` and `path3`.

```
grep -r --include=*.xml --include=*.js "your search string" path1 path2 path3
```

So you can search in a subset of the files for many directories, just providing the paths at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Run(terminal) the following command inside the directory. It will recursively check inside subdirectories too.

```
grep -r 'your string goes here' *
```

Answer (score -3):

Don't use grep. Download [Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) or [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep). They're both outstanding, and way faster than grep or ack with tons of options.

Comment: These maybe great tools but this doesn't answer how I would use these tools to accomplish what the OP is asking.