# Regex pattern for hexa decimal values

Tags: angularjs

I need a regular expression for ng-pattern which accepts only 0-9 and a-f 
only hexa decimal values.

Comment: 0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for a hexadecimal number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221362/regular-expression-for-a-hexadecimal-number)