# How to distinguish hexadecimal number and decimal number in Regex expression?

Tags: c#, regex

My English skill is poor because i'm not a native English speaker.
If rude expression exists in this article, please understand.

I am using regex library of .Net Core.
I wanted to distinguish hexadecimal number and decimal number so I written a code to do this.
But the code was not operated so I extract core logic that I want and created the below code on Test project newly.

```
string identPattern = "(?<rwC>[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*)";
string hexaPattern = "(?<iAZ>[0x][0-9]+)";
string decimalPattern = "(?<oKZ>[0-9]+)";
string pattern = string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", identPattern, hexaPattern, decimalPattern);

foreach (var data in Regex.Matches("0x10;", pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture))
{
    var matchData = data as Match;
}
```

If it executes the above code "0" of "0x10" string is matched.
This means "0x10" string is matched with decimalPattern ("(?[0-9]+)"). This is not result that I want.
I want that "0x10" string is matched with hexaPattern.

Why don't matched with hexaPattern? and How to solve this problem?

My test code and execute result is as below.

[image]

Thanks for reading.

Comment: See [Regular expression for a hexadecimal number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221362/regular-expression-for-a-hexadecimal-number/25724915)

Comment: Thank you the linked article is very useful for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error is in your hex pattern. you should not surround `0x` with `[]` as it means charset and will match only one character.

Try below for hex pattern

```regex
(?<iAZ>0x[0-9]+)
```

And if you don't want your decimal pattern to match your hex number, try adding `^` at the beginning of decimal pattern.