# Search for strings in files and report which strings DO NOT exist

Tags: string, file, search

I have a long list of short strings and a long list of text files to search in (actually nested folders of files to search in). I need to know which of the test strings do NOT exist in any of the files.

There are many methods to find strings in files and report where they are (for example, [FINDSTR](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)), but I've yet to find a way to only list the strings that can't be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tripp Kinetics for providing the framework for this answer, but I wanted to be able to use built-in Windows commands, rather than install new software, since I will be distributing this to others on our team. With a little research, here's what I came up with:

```
SET SEARCH_COUNT=0
SET FOUND_COUNT=0
SET NOT_FOUND_COUNT=0

FOR /F "tokens=1" %%G IN (list_of_strings.txt) DO (
    ECHO | SET /P unusedVar=Looking for %%G... 

    FINDSTR /ISPL /C:%%G "folder_to_search\*.*" >nul 2>&1

    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        ECHO Not found
        SET /A NOT_FOUND_COUNT=NOT_FOUND_COUNT+1
        ECHO %%G >> not_found.txt
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO Found!
        SET /A FOUND_COUNT=FOUND_COUNT+1
        ECHO %%G >> found.txt
    )

    SET /A SEARCH_COUNT=SEARCH_COUNT+1
)

ECHO(
ECHO Search complete.
ECHO(
ECHO Looked for %SEARCH_COUNT% strings
ECHO %FOUND_COUNT% found
ECHO %NOT_FOUND_COUNT% not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're in Windows.  It's easy to do this in Unix, but that's not necessarily an impediment.

You need a Bourne-compatible shell (/sh, /ksh, /bash, /zsh, etc.), grep and test.  You could either go hunting for the native Windows versions of the preceding, or install a bare minimum [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) with those packages.  I recommend the latter, since it's simpler to make the pieces work together.

Run this command in sh:

```
for each in `cat /path/to/list_of_strings.txt` ; do
    grep --silent $each `cat /another/path/to/list_of_files.txt`
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        echo $each
    fi
done
```

If you don't feel comfortable having that Cygwin install around afterwards, you can always delete it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. Is it possible to give it a directory of files to search rather than a text list? My original question was poorly worded.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my follow-up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121803/how-can-i-use-grep-to-find-a-word-inside-a-folder

Comment: Thanks for you help! This was just the direction I needed.