# where can I find magento ajax image loading gif?

Tags: magento

I am trying to locate the default ajax loader gif image in the skin directory. Can't find. How can I replace the default existing magento ajax loading gif?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use grep to find a word inside a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121803/how-can-i-use-grep-to-find-a-word-inside-a-folder)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to override magento ajax loading gif universally will be to place an image of the same name in your custom theme directory called `/images/opc-ajax-loader.gif`

So, for example:

```
/skin/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/images/opc-ajax-loader.gif
```